# Angular 4 add URL to innerhtml

Tags: json, angular, ionic2

I'm using angular 4 innerHtml element for parsing Html from the server.

```
  <div *ngFor="let html of htmlToRender">
    <div [innerHtml]="html"></div>
     </div>
```

I'm using API to get HTML from the server and the response I'm using JSON.parse() method to parse the response type. 
it gives me the array

```
   this.htmlToRender = JSON.parse(this.htmlToParse._body);
```

now the problem is when i'm rendering **this.htmltoRender** i may get some image or file URls which are having absolute path.
eg:

```
<img alt="" src="/Source/ImageBrowser/Image?path=logoCar.qd.png"
```

from the server, I will get such path... I need to add Url to access that source example: for the response, I need to append example "http://google.com"
ie.,.

```
<img alt="" src="http://google.com/Analytics/ImageBrowser/Image?path=logo.qd.png">
```

since parsing from the server they are not able to append 
so any idea how we can achieve this in angular 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace all urls after you get the result from the server using a regular expression. Look for all occurrences of `/Source/ImageBrowser/`, and replace them with your desired url.

```
var regExp = new RegExp(/\/Source\/ImageBrowser\/*/g);
this.htmlToRender = this.htmlToRender.replace(regExp,'http://google.com/Analytics/ImageBrowser/');
```

Comment: what if "/\/Source\/ImageBrowser\/*/g" is not constant?

Comment: if you have a few paths that you know about, you can do this simple matching technique on all the paths.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the occurance in Component itselef instead of in html for performance reasons,

**Since you have array in this.htmlToRender,**

```
this.htmlToRender.forEach(html => {
   html = html.replace("/Source", "http://google.com/Analytics");
})
```

If you want to replace using **regExp**

```
this.htmlToRender.forEach(html => {
   html = html.replace(/\/Source/i, "http://google.com/Analytics");
})
```

If `/Source/ImageBrowser` is not the same then  you can do,

```
this.htmlToRender.forEach(html => {
    let imageUrl = a.split('/');
    imageUrl = imageUrl[imageUrl.length - 1]
    imageUrl = "http://google.com/Analytics/ImageBrowser/" +imageUrl
    html = imageUrl
})
```

Comment: what if the "source" is not constant ?

Comment: Updated the answer please check

Comment: Hi thanks for reply.,. currently they may be handling from server side... if i get any chance to check with client side i will work on it...

Comment: yeah sure, check that and you can ask any doubts if it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens due to angulars security mechanisms. Try using the `DomSanitizer` as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/security).

Example:

```
updateVideoUrl(id: string) {
   // Appending an ID to a YouTube URL is safe.
   // Always make sure to construct SafeValue objects as
   // close as possible to the input data so
   // that it's easier to check if the value is safe.
   this.dangerousVideoUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id;
   this.videoUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.dangerousVideoUrl);
}
```